# Create UINavigationController in UITableViewController inside UITabBarController

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, xcode4, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

I have an application with based of **UITabBarController**, and inside one of the tabs I have **UITableViewController** to display "products", till here everything is working perfectly.

Now I want when clicking one of the cells inside the **UITableViewController** to open a **UINavigationController** to display **UIViewController** with details of that product.

I think the application hierarchy should be like the following:

```
UITabBarController (BASE) Level-1
  |
  |___ UITableViewController (PRODUCTS) Level-2
         |
         |___ UINavigationController Level-3
                |
                |___ UIViewController (PRODUCT DETAILS) Level-4
```

How to achieve Level-3 and Level-4?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5):

First You Will need to reset your hierarchy to something like this:

```
UITabBarController (BASE)
  |
  |___ UINavigationController
      |
      |___ UITableViewController (PRODUCTS)
        |
        |___ UIViewController (PRODUCT DETAILS)
```

You need to add a UINavigationController in the TabBarController, then you will use it to push the Product Detail.

to add a UINavigation on TabBarController:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *tableNavController_1 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:YourProductViewController_1] autorelease];
UINavigationController *table2NavController_2 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:YourProductViewController_2] autorelease];

tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tableNavController_1, table2NavController_2, nil];

//then add the controller to view like,
// this:
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

//or this:
[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

I recommend you to create a new UITableViewController for each *ProductViewController* and then use the delegate method: `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` for pushing the detail view:

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Nib name" bundle:nil];
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES]
[detailViewController release];
```

Comment: I really do appreciate your detailed reply, but its too difficult for me to re-design the application as I'm still a newbie. I'd really love if there's a way to add navigation to my table.

Comment: to have a UITableViewController whit navigation you need a UINavigationController. In your specific case you have to add a  UINavigationController "inside" the TabBarController, and the table "inside" the UINavigationController.. 
as I explain before

Comment: +1 for the first chart showing the hierarchy - placing the navigation controller between the tab controller and the initial table view made my seque to the "detail" view work!