# how can i create or add the tableviews in the tab bar application in Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

I am using the Tab bar based application and in First view (or first tab) i want to view the table view from which i select should navigate. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  see this url and [implement](http://maybelost.com/2011/10/tutorial-storyboard-in-xcode-4-2-with-navigation-controller-and-tabbar-controller-part1/)

Answer (score 0):

Just put your tableViewController into the `tabBarController.viewControllers`'s array:

```
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tableViewController, commonViewController_1, commonViewController_2, commonViewController_3, nil];
```

I suggest you do more searching on Google by yourself. :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to apple programming guide they have explained it properly. U can refer to this thread as well [Create UINavigationController in UITableViewController inside UITabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731003/create-uinavigationcontroller-in-uitableviewcontroller-inside-uitabbarcontroller)